# Converting Stream to MemoryStream

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, stream, memorystream

I'm having trouble converting my Stream to a MemoryStream. i want to do this, because i want to delete the file i have uploaded to the FTP server. When i try to delete or Move the file to another folder i get an exception that tells me the file is beeing used by another process. The purpose of this app is to Uploade the files to a FTP server, and Move the file to an archive folder. This is my code:

```
public void UploadLocalFiles(string folderName)
        {
            try
            {

                string localPath = @"\\Mobileconnect\filedrop_to_ssis\" + folderName;
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(localPath);
                string path;

                foreach (string filepath in files)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
                    localFileNames = files;
                    reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("ftp:......./inbox/" + fileName));
                    reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
                    reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                    reqFTP.ServicePoint.ConnectionLimit = files.Length;
                    reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
                    reqFTP.EnableSsl = true;
                    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Certificate;
                    reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(localPath + @"\" + fileName);
                    FileStream fileStream = fileInfo.OpenRead();

                    int bufferLength = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

                    Stream uploadStream = reqFTP.GetRequestStream();

                    int contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                    var memoStream = new MemoryStream();
                    uploadStream.CopyTo(memoStream);
                    memoStream.ToArray();
                    uploadStream.Close();

                    while (contentLength != 0)
                    {
                        memoStream.Write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                        contentLength = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);

                    }
                }

                reqFTP.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error in GetLocalFileList method!!!!!" + e.Message);
            }

        }
```

When i reach this line of code:

```
 uploadStream.CopyTo(memoStream);
```

i get an exception telling me that this Stream cant read.

How can i solve this?

Comment: You need to finish reading your upload stream before you can move the file.

Comment: the uploadstream is locking the file, and i cant see why and where

Answer (score 1):

`uploadStream.CopyTo(memoStream);` fails because you are trying to copy write-only FTP request stream. I'm not sure what your code is doing (way to many copy/read operations in one place) so I can't recommend on a way of fixing it.

Also your `FileStream` is locking the file. Your code missing `using` constructs or `Close` or `Dispose` calls on at least `fileStream` object.

Side note: using `using` is significantly easier that writing `try`/`finally` for each stream by hand (note that your code does not close streams in case of exceptions since you don't make calls to close inside `finally`).

Comment: when surrounding my filestream with `using` the applikation would not uploade the file to the FTP server for some reason